# Passing StateMachine ARN through enviroment variable using Serverless.yml

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

While testing I am getting the following message:

```
 Serverless Warning --------------------------------------
 A valid service attribute to satisfy the declaration     
'self:resources.Outputs.StateMachine.Value' could not be found.
```

excerpts of the serverless.yml

```
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: us-east-1 
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  versionFunctions: false
  environment:
    statemachine_arn: ${self:resources.Outputs.StateMachine.Value}
```

State Functions

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    updateMetric:
       name: updateMetric
       definition:
         Comment: "A state machine to update data"
         StartAt: getMetric
          ........
          ........
```

### Outputs

```
resources:
  - ${file(./resources/dynamodb-table.yml)}
  - Outputs:
      StateMachine:
        Value:
          Ref: UpdateMetric
```

All I am trying to pass the ARN of the state machine so that I can start the stateMachine
from a lamda function.

It seems my reference in outputs section not working or I am not calling it properly here:

```
 environment:
    statemachine_arn: ${self:resources.Outputs.StateMachine.Value}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: did you solve this? i'm also having same problem

Comment: Yes. I did.  Passed the variable using function's env variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try capitalising the first letter of updateMetric.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).